# filling multidimensional array with unique numbers in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, random, unique, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to write a code that will fill array with unique numbers.

I could write the code separately for 1, 2 and 3 dimensional arrays but number of `for` cycles grow to "infinity".

this is the code for 2D array:

```
static void fillArray(int[,] array)
        {
            Random rand = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    array[i, j] = rand.Next(1, 100);
                    for (int k = 0; k < j; k++)
                        if (array[i, k] == array[i, j])
                            j--;
                }
            }

            print_info(array);
        }
```

Is it possible to do something like this for **n**-dimensional arrays?

Comment: Your code only checks that the number is unique within the same slice of the array. Is that the intention, or should the number be unique in the entire array?

Comment: ups. I never noticed that. you are right. It should be unique in entire array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach is to start with a 1-d array of unique numbers, which you can shuffle, and then slot into appropriate places in your real array.

Here is the main function:

```
private static void Initialize(Array array)
{
    var rank = array.Rank;
    var dimensionLengths = new List<int>();
    var totalSize = 1;
    int[] arrayIndices = new int[rank];

    for (var dimension = 0; dimension < rank; dimension++)
    {
        var upperBound = array.GetLength(dimension);
        dimensionLengths.Add(upperBound);
        totalSize *= upperBound;
    }

    var singleArray = new int[totalSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < totalSize; i++) singleArray[i] = i;
    singleArray = Shuffle(singleArray);

    for (var i = 0; i < singleArray.Length; i++)
    {
        var remainingIndex = i;
        for (var dimension = array.Rank - 1; dimension >= 0; dimension--)
        {
            arrayIndices[dimension] = remainingIndex%dimensionLengths[dimension];
            remainingIndex /= dimensionLengths[dimension];
        }

        // Now, set the appropriate cell in your real array:
        array.SetValue(singleArray[i], arrayIndices);
    }
}
```

The key in this example is the `array.SetValue(value, params int[] indices)` function.  By building up the correct list of indices, you can use this function to set an arbitrary cell in your array.

Here is the `Shuffle` function:

```
private static int[] Shuffle(int[] singleArray)
{
    var random = new Random();
    for (int i = singleArray.Length; i > 1; i--)
    {
        // Pick random element to swap.
        int j = random.Next(i); // 0 <= j <= i-1
        // Swap.
        int tmp = singleArray[j];
        singleArray[j] = singleArray[i - 1];
        singleArray[i - 1] = tmp;
    }
    return singleArray;
}
```

And finally a demonstration of it in use:

```
var array1 = new int[2,3,5];
Initialize(array1);
var array2 = new int[2,2,3,4];
Initialize(array2);
```

My strategy assigns sequential numbers to the original 1-d array to ensure uniqueness, but you can adopt a different strategy for this as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Rank](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.rank.aspx) property to get the total number of dimentions in your array

To insert use [SetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkekac1b.aspx) method

Answer (score 0):

In the first two for loops you are analysing the array properly (`i` and `j` go from the start to the end of the corresponding dimension). The problem comes in the most internal part where you introduce a "correction" which actually provokes an endless loop for `j`.

```
First iteration:
- First loop: i = 0;
- Second loop: j = 0;
- Third loop: j = -1

Second iteration
- First loop: i = 0;
- Second loop: j = 0;
- Third loop: j = -1
. etc., etc.
```

(I start my analysis in the moment when the internal loop is used for the first time. Also bear in mind that the exact behaviour cannot be predicted as far as random numbers are involved. But the idea is that you are making the `j` counter back over and over by following an arbitrary rule).

What you want to accomplish exactly? What is this last correction (the one provoking the endless loop) meant to do?

If the only thing you intend to do is checking the previously stored values, you have to rely on a different variable (j2, for example) which will not affect any of the loops above:

```
  int j2 = j;
  for (int k = 0; k < j2; k++)
       if (array[i, k] == array[i, j2])
         j2--;
```